# How to call a button which is declared commonly to two different positions in a web page in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, button, commonjs

I have written a class component in reactjs inside render i am calling a button in two different positons with two diff param.

```
{this.applebutton('tutor')}
```

```
{this.applebutton('student')}
```

And the button i have declared is :

```
applebutton = (type) => {
        <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 mt-2">                                             
        <AppleLogin
            clientId={globalVariable.APPLE_ID}
            redirectURI="https://test.example.com/sign-up"
            usePopup={true}
            callback={(e) => this.getAppleToken(e, `${type}`)} // Catch the response
            scope="email name"
            responseMode="query"
            render={renderProps => (
                <div
                    className='btn btn-google'
                    onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                    disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                >
                    <AppleFilled className='btn-apple' />
                    Continue with Apple
                </div>
            )}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
        />
    </div>
    }
```

but i am getting this error

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

What i am doing wrong i am new to reactjs

Comment: `applebutton` has no `return` statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the component names with capital letters. For not render issue, you need to use a return before the write JSX. Also its better to usage of curly brackets for define parameters.

If you re-write like this, I believe that it will work.

```
AppleButton = ({type}) => {
 return <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 mt-2">                                             
        <AppleLogin
            clientId={globalVariable.APPLE_ID}
            redirectURI="https://test.example.com/sign-up"
            usePopup={true}
            callback={(e) => this.getAppleToken(e, `${type}`)} // Catch the response
            scope="email name"
            responseMode="query"
            render={renderProps => (
                <div
                    className='btn btn-google'
                    onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                    disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                >
                    <AppleFilled className='btn-apple' />
                    Continue with Apple
                </div>
            )}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
        />
    </div>
    }
```

And you can use it on this way:

```
<AppleButton type="tutor" />
```

Comment: Thank u i also have another issue can u pls help me with that.
My website login page has two containers one for a student & another one for tutor both have the same url ex: www.testex.com/sign-in , When i implement apple sign in button for either one of student or tutor it is working fine. But when i try to implement on both the containers then i am getting an error as ReferenceError: AppleID is not defined. My webapge is developed on reactjs. My doubt is can i use two apple login button on  my sign in webpage one for the student & another one for the tutor.